# Subprocess.call how to espeak the components in a list

Tags: python, list, raspberry-pi, subprocess, espeak

```
import subprocess

digit = [1,2,3,4]
subprocess.call('espeak -s 120 -ven ' + str(digit) +'--stdout | aplay', shell=True)
```

The sound that i hear is only "One", which is only the first component of the list. How should I write the code to make it announce "One-Two-Three-Four"?

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to iterate over `digits` (note that I changed the name of the list to `digits`). While you are at it you may want to use `str.format` for readability.

```
import subprocess

digits = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for digit in digits:
    subprocess.call('espeak -s 120 -ven {} --stdout | aplay'.format(digit), shell=True)
```

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace, thanks for the answer. I think it is very close, but the output of the audio is `"one-stout-two-stout-three-stout-four-stout"` Why is "stout" being spoken out? Sorry, I just started learning python.

Comment: @sam I'm not sure as I'm not familiar with espeak. It may be sensitive to the whitespace before the `--stdout` flag which is missing from my example. Try removing it: `subprocess.call('espeak -s 120 -ven {}--stdout | aplay'.format(digit), shell=True)`

Comment: Tried it. Still the same output, `"one-stout-two-stout-three-stout-four-stout"`. Thanks for helping anyway.